# Is it possible to detect when a user "clicks" an element with the keyboard (while navigating witht the tab key)?

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I have an element that is selectable through the tabindex as normal, but when I press enter/space, it doesn't trigger the click action, so I thought maybe I can write some javascript to detect when the user "clicks" the element, and trigger the click function.

I assume I could just detect when the user presss enter / space, and trigger the click function, but I don't know if there are other keys that are supposed to function as a click, or if it's possible to bind it to another key.

Comment: what kind of element is it? most triggerable elements should fire automatically on enter (buttons, links...)

Comment: It's a div, from a wordpress plugin, so it's not really viable to change the code on the page itself, which is why I'm trying to do this with javascript.

Comment: A `div` isn't Tab focusable by default , has it been set with a `tabindex`?

Comment: Yes. I wrote a little line of javascript to set the tabindex to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do it like this :

```
document.querySelectorAll('.elements-class').onkeyup = function(event) {

    event = event || window.event
    var keycode = event.charCode || event.keyCode

    if (keycode === 13 || keycode === 32) {

         //trigger action done here.

    }

}
```

Comment: That is my plan so far, but isn't it possible for the user to change bind this function to another key (maybe they use 'e' for clicking or something)?

Comment: @AlanFernandes nobody is going to use `e` to *click on something*. Users know how the keyboard works, unless they are learning - **the common way**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not quite sure on the best way to handle this situation, but for now I have come up with this:

```
$('.my-div').on('keypress', function(e) {
    $(this).trigger('click');
    return !(e.keyCode == 32);
    //This last line prevents the default behavior of spacebar (scrolling down the page)
});
```

I'll probably go with @Yaser's answer, but I though it could be useful for someone else.

But as I said, I'm still not quite certain on how to handle this situation, because I don't know enough about tab navigation to be sure people can't have the click function bound to another key or something like that.